# Designing a recursive function that uses digit_sum to calculate sum of digits

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def digit_sum(n):
    if n==0 or n==1:
        return n
    else:
        return n+digit_sum(n-1)

def digital_root(n):

    if n<10:
        return n
    else:
        return digit_sum((n // 10) + n % 10)
```

I am trying to use `digit_sum` to calculate the sum of digits of `digital_root` can someone help me please. I am trying to use a recursive function for `digital_root`.

Running the file in Python shell:

```
digital_root(1969)
```

This should calculate 1+9+6+9=25 then since 25 is greater than 10 it should then calculate the sum of its digits 2+5 so that the final answer is 7.

Comment: It would help if you  gave an example of what you would like the function usage to look like, along with input and expected output values.

Comment: Have you tried adding print statements to see where the calculation goes wrong?

Comment: Your digit sum function is wrong, at least the recursing part.

Comment: There's a simple solution to this problem: `digital_root = lambda n: 1+(n-1)%9`. If you need to handle zeros then slightly more complex: `digital_root = lambda n: n-9*int((n-1)/9)`. See [Digital Root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root)

Answer (score 5):

To get the last digit of a (positive integer) number you can calculate the modulo:

```
last_digit = n % 10
```

The remainder of the number (excluding the last place) is:

```
rest = (n - last_digit) / 10
```

This should in theory be enough to split a number and add the digits:

```
def sum_digits(n):
    if n < 10:
        return n
    else:
        last_digit = n % 10
        rest = n // 10
        # or using divmod (thanks @warvariuc):
        # rest, last_digit = divmod(n, 10)
        return last_digit + sum_digits(rest)

sum_digits(1969)  # 25
```

If you want to apply this recursivly until you have a value smaller than 10 you just need to call this function as long as that condition is not fulfilled:

```
def sum_sum_digit(n):
    sum_ = sum_digit(n)
    if sum_ < 10:
        return sum_
    else:
        return sum_sum_digit(sum_)

sum_sum_digit(1969) # 7
```

Just if you're interested another way to calculate the sum of the digits is by converting the number to a string and then adding each character of the string:

```
def sum_digit(n):
    return sum(map(int, str(n)))
    # or as generator expression:
    # return sum(int(digit) for digit in str(n))
```

Comment: @warvariuc I always wondered what that function is good for. I added it as alternative. Thank you!

Comment: I can't use that method MSeifert. I need to use my digit_sum function.

Comment: I was wondering how I can repeat the function without using a for loop or a while

Answer (score 2):

If you really require a recursive solution without using any loops (`for`, `while`) then you can always recurse again to ensure a single digit:

```
def digital_root(n):
    if n < 10:
        return n
    a, b = divmod(n, 10)
    b += digital_root(a)
    return digital_root(b)

>>> digital_root(1969)
7
```

Or you could just not recurse at all:

```
def digital_root(n):   # n > 0
    return 1+(n-1)%9

>>> digital_root(1969)
7
```

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
digitSum = 0
solution = 0
S = raw_input()
S = list(map(int, S.split()))
#print S
for i in S:
    digitSum += i
#print digitSum
singleDigit = len(str(digitSum)) == 1
if singleDigit == True: solution = digitSum
while singleDigit == False:
    solution = sum( [ int(str(digitSum)[i]) for i in range( 0, len(str(digitSum))) ] )
    digitSum = solution
    singleDigit = len(str(solution)) == 1
print(solution)
```